# How bad is it to storage beer at 20 to 25 degrees celsius?

Tags: storage

Unfortunately I don't have a basement or a different room where it's between 10-15 degrees. Since it's summer, the temperature in the house is between 20 and 25 degrees. All of my beers are stored in a closet where it is 23 degrees at the moment. I have 3 year old Orvals, Barleywines, IPAs and some other beers. Is this going to damage the beer? Or shouldn't I worry about it?

Comment: For sure it is a problem if they are not pasturized

Comment: @Papparazzi I know for sure that all of the IPA's aren't pasteurized, not sure about the other beers. Also I can't store all of them in my fridge, because I have around 25 beers at the moment.

Comment: If I was sure I would post an answer but I think you have a problem.

Comment: @Paparazzi I might pick up a wine cooler and use it for my beers. That will resolve the problem. But im still interested if these temperatures will damage or make the beer go bad.

Answer (score 2):

According to this non pasturized <45°F (<7.2°C)
And even then a shelf life of 60 - 90 days

It might be time for a party

[Beer Storage](http://www.gcca.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Beer.pdf)

As for wine cooler.  For shelf life the colder the better as long as you don't freeze.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also contacted a brewery and they suggested to always store IPA's in the fridge. But he told me that the temperature for the barleywines isn't a big problem if it doesnt exceed 24 degrees celsius. it isn't the most ideal temperature though.

Comment: @Bas Cool.  Beer is not wine - it is not meant to be held.  Buy beer - drink beer.   Buy more beer - drink more beer.

Comment: true, except for some beers. Barleywines for example, they can be aged for years and achieve a better taste.